# Determine the size of the records returned by a database server (Kb,Mb)?

Tags: database

Is there a way to determine the size of the records returned by the database server?

Comment: What interests you exactly?  The total amount of data transferred between the server and the client?  Why?  Memory footprint in the client process?  Amount of data transferred over the network?  Are you over a network, or over socket, or over loopback?

Comment: Can you clarify "size of the records"?  A COUNT will tell you the # of records, if you want to see the width (bytes), you could do a dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate the record size(s):

- **in the client application** by altering the code to sum up and print the sizes of the fields you retrieved (you *need to specify whether you can alter the client code*), or
- **at the OS level**, by using `strace` or `truss` to trace the byte amounts reported by `read` on the file handle associated to the database connection (using `lsof` to get the mapping between file handle and TCP/IP connection), provided that the OS is a flavour of Unix (you *need to specify the operating system that either your client or database are running on*), or
- **at the network level** by using a tool such as `wireshark` or `tcpdump`, provided that the client connects to the server through a physical network interface (not through the loopback -- you *need to specify how your client application is connecting to the database*), or
- **at the database level** by enabling appropriate logging or by looking at the database statistics (e.g. `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "my_table"` on MySQL, `SELECT SUM(avg_width) FROM pg_stats WHERE table_name LIKE 'my_table'` for Postgres, etc.) for the average row size of the tables of interest, provided that the database supports it (you *need to specify the database you are using*)  Otherwise you can compute your own statistics from a database dump.